# error with io stream

Tags: c++

What is the problem with the last two statements in the code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "2 + 4 = " << 2 + 4 << endl;
cout << "2 * 4 = " << 2 * 4 << endl;
cout << "2 | 4 = " << 2 | 4 << endl;
cout << "2 & 4 = " << 2 & 4 << endl;
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the problem with the last two statements in the code?

Operator precedence. `|` and `&` have lower precedence than `<<`, so `cout << "2 & 4 = " << 2 & 4 << endl;` gets parsed as `(cout << "2 & 4 = " << 2) & (4 << endl;)`.

> What should I do to fix this?

Put parens around `2 | 4` and `2 & 4`.

Answer (score 3):

Put the expression in parentheses.  The `<<` operator is taking precedence over the bitwise operators.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout << "2 + 4 = " << 2 + 4 << endl;
  cout << "2 * 4 = " << 2 * 4 << endl;
  cout << "2 | 4 = " << (2 | 4) << endl;
  cout << "2 & 4 = " << (2 & 4) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```